# USA West Coast - Buying a SIM card

Tags: usa, cellphones

I'm going to visit California next year. I'm from Europe. Since my current carrier doesn't provide good plans for roaming in the USA, I'm looking for a service that can offer a SIM card with data plans to foreign visitors. I have googled some and there are several options out there.

- Prepaidzero.com
- Simoptions

These are just a few I have been looking at. I'm a little concerned about buying from these companies because it doesn't seem like they own the networks like AT&T, T-Mobile does. What I'm looking for is a SIM card with a data plan that gives me 10 GB+, which I can plug into my phone or a hotspot device.

I'm hoping anyone has experience in buying SIM cards when traveling in the USA that they can share. What would you recommend and is there anything I should watch out for?

I see there's [a wiki about this](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Prepaid_SIM_with_data) linked from another answer on SE. I'm hoping someone has personal experience beyond what is covered by the wiki.

Comment: When we first arrived in the US for a month vacation we just went into Walmart or Best-Buy (can't remember) and bought a prepaid SIM card.  Cost us $50, gave us unlimited calling/texting and 5GB of data for the month.  There may be some which offer larger data packages, or even unlimited data, but they will probably cost more

Comment: T-Mobile offers a “traveler plan” which is good for 21 days (not extendable) with unlimited talk (in the US only) and text (including many foreign countries) and 2Gb of 4G data for $30. They also have a (seemingly unadvertised) version with 10Gb for $50. My brother lives overseas and when he last visited, this is what he used. You can go into any T-Mobile store to get these.

Comment: @DoxyLover I hope that's 2 GB (gigabytes) and not 2 Gb (gigabits) - they're different by a factor of eight!

Comment: My bad. Yes 2/10 **GB**.

Comment: Last time I was there I bought a SIM at Walgreens (a drug store chain). It was something like $40 for the service and another $10 for a whole whack of physical SIM cards.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. Since many of you advice just buying this in a store I think i'll do that. If I remember this post next year when I visit USA, I try to update it with my experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service like Simlystore or buy a card from Amazon.
Source: [USA Reisetipps](https://www.usa-reisetipps.net/leben-in-den-usa/handytarife)